# Why is Android's MediaStore.Audio.Album.ALBUM_ID causing an IllegalStateException error?

Tags: java, android, media

I'm trying to grab album information from **MediaStore**. I can get the name and artist very easily but for some reason the **ALBUM_ID** column is giving me an error when I try to access it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:450)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51    )
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
at sage.musicplayer.MainActivity.getAlbumList(MainActivity.java:1540)
at sage.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:238)
```

I can't seem to find a solution. Any help is appreciated! Below is the method I have to grab the album information and add them to an *ArrayList*.

```
public ArrayList<Album> getAlbumList() {
    ArrayList<Album> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    /*String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS
    };*/

    Cursor albumCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if(albumCursor != null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int albumName = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
        int albumArtist = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST);
        int albumID = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID);

         do {
            String thisAlbumName = albumCursor.getString(albumName);
            String thisAlbumArtist = albumCursor.getString(albumArtist);
            String thisAlbumID = albumCursor.getString(albumID);//this line is giving me an error

            temp.add(new Album(thisAlbumName, thisAlbumArtist, thisAlbumID));
        }while(albumCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: what are the values of albumName, albumArtist and albumID? use `Log.d` to log them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced this issue. You can easily solve this issue by changing

`int albumID = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID);`

TO

`int albumID = albumCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);`

That is you need to use `_ID` whenever you want `AlbumID` of the Album. I have no idea why `MediaStore` developers used `_ID` instead of `ALBUM_ID`, etc stuff.

Comment: Thank you! You're the best, bae!

Comment: In my case it worked with `string a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID));`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a Motorola g6 and it exhibits the same problem. Google pixel 2xl is fine instead. Not respecting the Android specifications is an incredible source of bugs and silly from Motorola. Now I have a bug cause `MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM_ID` doesn't exist on Motorola, and in that filter there is no _ID. The worst is that you will never discover such bug unless you test on a bugged device. Shame on Motorola.